# Change title on page

Tags: php, url, get

I have the following code that change Title on the page:

class.php

```
<?php
    class Title_And_Page
    {
        public $pagekey;
        public $title;
        public $page;
        private $pages = array(
                    'start_page'    => array("Startsida", "start_page.php"),
                    'products'      => array("Produkter", "products.php"),
                    'max_ot'        => array("Max-OT", "max_ot.php"),
                    'blog'          => array("Blogg", "blog.php"),
                    'tools'         => array("Verktyg", "tools.php"),
                    'about_us'      => array("Om oss", "about_us.php"));

        public function __construct($pagekey)
        {
            $this->pagekey      = $pagekey;
        }

        public function setTitle()
        {
            if(array_key_exists($this->pagekey, $this->pages))
            {
                $this->title = $this->pages[$this->pagekey][0]; //Returns the value in title, that it gets when the constructs is run
                return $this->title;
            }
        }

        public function includePage()
        {
            if(array_key_exists($this->pagekey, $this->pages))
            {
                $this->page = $this->pages[$this->pagekey][1]; //Returns the value in page, that will be included
                return $this->page;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Here is my some code from my index.php

```
    if(isset($_GET['page']))
    {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }

    $page_title = new Title_And_Page($page);
<title><?= $page_title->setTitle(); ?></title>
<li id="info"><a href="?page=products" class='clickme'>Produkter</a></li>
        <li id="info"><a href="?page=max_ot">MAX-OT</a></li>
        <li id="info"><a href="?page=blog">Blogg</a></li>
        <li id="info"><a href="?page=tools">Verktyg</a></li>
        <li id="info"><a href="?page=about_us">Om oss</a></li>
```

This works. However, I have articles in the blog page that contains "Read more"-links. When I click on a "Read more"-link, the URL changes to this: index.php?page=blog&readmore_from_firstpage=1&article_header=Vilken kolhydrat är bäst att äta efter träningen?

How can I change the title of the page, to the value in $_GET['article_header'] as you can see above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just extend your GET checks:

```
if(isset($_GET['article_header']))
{
    $page = $_GET['article_header'];
}
elseif(isset($_GET['page']))
{
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}
```

But since you're checking in your class whether that page is whitelisted, you'd need to either add another variable to force avoiding such check or simply just to print out the title if `article_header` is present.

Here's an example of the latter:

```
$avoidClass = false;
if(isset($_GET['article_header']))
{
    $page = $_GET['article_header'];
    $avoidClass = true;
}
elseif(isset($_GET['page']))
{
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}
```

Then in HTML:

```
<title><?= $avoidClass ? $page : $page_title->setTitle(); ?></title>
```

---

Or, probably the simplest way:

```
if(isset($_GET['article_header']))
{
    $page_title = $_GET['article_header'];
}
elseif(isset($_GET['page']))
{
    $page_title = new Title_And_Page($_GET['page'])->setTitle();
}
else
{
    $page_title = 'Default title here';
}
```

HTML

```
<title><?= $page_title ?></title>
```